# insert pickle object to database using pyodbc

Tags: python, blob, pickle, pyodbc

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
keypoints_database = pickle.load( open( "5958.p", "rb" ) )

sql = 'INSERT INTO tb_fpdata (Std_SymbolNo , FP_Descriptors) VALUES (5958 , ?)' , pyodbc.Binary(keypoints_database)
```

I got the following error:

[image: error message]

How can I save the object to the database?

Comment: If you already have a file containing the serialized (pickled) object then why not just read that file as a stream of bytes and then write that byte stream to a binary column (e.g., VARBINARY(max))?

Comment: I was able to write the binary stream to the database. Now I want to retrieve the binary stream and convert it back to pickle object.
Is there any way??

Answer (score 5):

So you have a binary file containing a pickled object. A hex dump of the file looks like this:

```
00000000: 8004 9515 0000 0000 0000 007d 9428 8c03  ...........}.(..
00000010: 666f 6f94 4b01 8c03 6261 7294 4b02 752e  foo.K...bar.K.u.
```

You can save the object to a binary column, then read it back and unpickle it via `pickle.loads` like so:

```python
import pyodbc
import pickle

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    r'SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDb;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE #test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, pkl VARBINARY(max))")

# read pre-pickled object from file and save to table
with open(r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    sql = "INSERT INTO #test (id, pkl) VALUES (?, ?)"
    params = (1, f.read())
    crsr.execute(sql, params)

# read it back from database and unpickle it
pickled_data = crsr.execute("SELECT pkl FROM #test WHERE id=1").fetchval()
unpickled_object = pickle.loads(pickled_data)

print(unpickled_object)
# {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

Comment: Is this example for Python 2 or 3? With Python3 and MySQL, this approach results in `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'xxÂ\x81L\x0f' at line 5 (1064) (SQLParamData)`. I assume that is due to the difference of handling binary strings?

Comment: @bluenote10 - I'm fairly certain that it would have been for Python 3; I started avoiding Python 2 quite a while ago. I just tried [this code](https://pastebin.com/cdUX6FbX) in Python 3.8 against a MySQL 5.6.13 server using pyodbc version 4.0.30 and myodbc8a.dll version 08.00.0018 and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It looks like the problem has to do with the actual content and/or length of the binary and/or other values present in the insert. I still need to narrow down the problem, but it could be an issue in pyodbc or the MySQL ODBC driver. In any case I can confirm that the example works in theory for Python 3.